# backtick in Perl printing output on terminal

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the output of a command in a variable and checking whether its matching with other variable.

```
   $login1=`ssh ****************** date`;
```

This command when typed manually will expect a prompt " Password: " . When i run it from the script it is ruuning that command and printing that prompt waiting for user to enter, but i dont need that. I just need to get that output and compare

```
     if($login1=~ /Password:/)
            {   
              print " yes";
            }
         else
              {
                print "No ";
               }
```

However the script is just stopping at Password prompt . Please suggest me on how to achieve this .

Comment: That's `ssh` blocking for user input. What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: It's stopping because `Password:` is not a complete line with a line end, so it's still waiting for the line end.

Comment: I just want to capture that commands output . I dont want to send anything there . But it is printing on my screen . I just want to obtain its output and compare if its Password or something else.

Comment: Yes ssh is blocking for user input , I just wanted to check if its blocking or not thats all.. If its blocking i have to print "yes" else "No".

Comment: I don't think the "Password: " string will be written to standard output, but instead will be written directly to the terminal.

Comment: @ooga I dont want that to happen sir, I just need to detect whether password is coming or not and later compare it as shown above.

Comment: You don't understand. The command substitution (the backticks) capture text from standard output. I don't believe that line is sent to standard output, so the backticks cannot capture it.

Comment: So how to achieve my solution . Please suggest

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can u suggest me a solution.

Comment: Password interaction goes to the process tty. If you want to capture that you will have to use IO::Pty or Expect.

Comment: @salva Can u please give an example

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect would be the best way to do this, as using ssh makes the shell interactive, and starts a remote session tty.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `-f` flag for `ssh`:

> ```
>  -f      Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.
>          This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
>          passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This
>          implies -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a
>          remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
> ```

If you want to avoid passwords, set up a public/private key pair with no passphrase (dangerous, but much less dangerous than putting a password in a script) and copy the public key to the remote site. IIRC, it goes something like this:

```
localhost $ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t ecdsa -N '' -f ./datekey
localhost $ scp ./datekey.pub remotehost:/tmp
localhost $ ssh remotehost
(login)
remotehost $ cat /tmp/datekey.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
remotehost $ logout

localhost $ ssh -i ./datekey remotehost date
```

Make sure you store `./datekey` somewhere no other user can access it at all -- not even read access.

---

If you're just trying to detect, you might simply need to feed it EOF to get it to move along:

```
$login1=`ssh ****************** date < /dev/null`;
```

Comment: No please see my comment above . I am not supposed to change anything in that command .

Comment: i used /dev/null . But it is not moving along , but printing password on the screen .

Comment: I think its directly printing on terminal and not capturing it . So how to achieve this . Please suggest

Comment: You can also use `ssh -o "BatchMode yes"` instead of using the `< /dev/null` trick to force it into non-interactive mode.